# Can we make a page saying primary debugging in WordPress

Tags: feature-request

Can we make a page saying the primary way of debugging in WordPress in brief?

- The disabling of all the plugins,
- The switching to a default theme,
- The turning of WP_DEBUG on,
- Then the enabling of plugin one by one, etc.

...with a sum-up direction on how to ask...

I enabled this on a local forum and questions are now coming with more debug information, and most of the primary level questions are not coming now, because they themselves solving their problems.

As we can easily add `[help]` shortcode to let the user direct to a page, can we make another, like `[primary]`, to let them informed about the primary steps of debugging in the comment field?

I already [had a question with idea](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/cut-out-off-topic-questions-an-idea) on informing users about OnTopic and OffTopic to cut the OffTopic Queries to minimal.

Anyway, can we think of it this way, or a better way perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is even a page for that: the [tag wiki page for `debug`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info). Feel free to edit that page, add useful information, so we have a canonical resource.

Comment: Did it. Have a look please.